# Network error with Reed API fetch request & basic auth

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I am trying to make a request to the REED jobs API although I am getting the error: `TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource`. The call is being made in a React component. The Reed API states `You will need to include your api key for all requests in a basic authentication http header as the username, leaving the password empty.` This is the part that confuses me and I do not know how to configure the fetch in this way. To help with this, I have sent the API call from Postman and have managed to get response successfully. Because of this,  I used the code generation function of Postman to make the below call, but it does not work:

```
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Authorization", `${process.env.REACT_APP_REED_KEY}==`);

    var requestOptions = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: myHeaders,
    };

    fetch("https://www.reed.co.uk/api/1.0/search?keywords=accountant&location=london&employerid=123&distancefromlocation=15", requestOptions)
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((result) => console.log(result))
      .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
```

Update:

I have changed the code to the below. Unfortunately, I am still getting an error. I am also now getting a new error: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.reed.co.uk/api/1.0/search?keywords=accountant&location=london&employerid=123&distancefromlocation=15. (Reason: CORS preflight response did not succeed).`

Updated code:

```
   import { encode } from "base-64";

    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Authorization", `Basic ${encode(process.env.REACT_APP_REED_KEY)}`);

    var requestOptions = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: myHeaders,
    };

    fetch("https://www.reed.co.uk/api/1.0/search?keywords=accountant&location=london&employerid=123&distancefromlocation=15", requestOptions)
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((result) => console.log(result))
      .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
```

Comment: 1. It's strange that you add `==` at the end of the base64 string. Not every base64 string has it, it's padding based on the length of the input string. Use an actual base64 encoding. 2. Does REACT_APP_REED_KEY include the string `Basic` ? Can't tell from your example

Comment: 1: The ```==``` was given from Postman; I believe there would normally be a password there but Reed does not require one. I tried removing it but changes nothing. I will try and give base64 encoding a go. 2: It doesn't include ```Basic``` , just the key.

Comment: If they require basic auth, then the string `Basic` must be in there. Read up on Basic auth, it's better than guessing how it might work.

Comment: Please could you check my update?

Comment: Looks like you fixed the first problem. This new CORS-related problem is a different one and there's a _ton_ of duplicates on this website about what CORS is. Chances are that reeds.co.uk does not let you do this on purpose.